# append content to div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried appending content to a div using a jQuery function. It gets added if I specify the id of the div manually. If I specify the id as a argument to function, it's not working.

```js
function addcontent(TargetDiv) {
  $(TargetDiv).append('Some text here');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addcontent('divTable');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="divTable"></div>
hai
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qumicu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: s. it works, thanks guys

Comment: Feel free to delete. It is not useful after you fixed the typo

Answer (score 2):

You need the `#` prepended to the id to find it:

```
function addcontent(TargetDiv)
{

  $("#" + TargetDiv).append('Some text here');        

}
```